# div tag not populating, using selenium python, inner HTML

Tags: python, selenium, innerhtml

I'm trying to access what appears to be a hidden table within a div tag on the following page:

[whoscored.com](https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/959574/LiveStatistics/England-Premier-League-2015-2016-West-Bromwich-Albion-Stoke)

...under the link "Passing"

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
base_url = "https://www.whoscored.com/Matches/959574/LiveStatistics/England-Premier-League-2015-2016-West-Bromwich-Albion-Stoke"
driver.get(base_url)
```

First i click the link:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Passing")
elem.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Next, I try to get the innerhtml of the tag where it appears this table resides.

```
demo_div = driver.find_element_by_id("live-player-home-passing")
print demo_div.get_attribute('innerHTML')
print driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML", demo_div)
```

But the innerhtml comes up empty in that tag. Very frustrating, because I see the data on the page, but can't figure out a way to grab it.

Any ideas? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Edit: Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="live-player-home-passing" class="statistics-table-tab">
  <div id="statistics-table-home-passing-loading"></div>
  <div id="statistics-table-home-passing"></div>
  <div id="statistics-table-home-passing-column-legend"></div>
</div>
```

The data is within 3rd tag, but only visible when I do "Inspect Element":

```
<div id="live-player-home-passing" class="statistics-table-tab" style="display: block;">
    <div id="statistics-table-home-passing" data-fwsc="1">
        <table id="top-player-stats-summary-grid" class="grid with-centered-columns hover">
            <thead id="player-table-statistics-head">
            .....

            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show the html ?

Comment: i posted the HTML - one example where I just view page source, and the other when i click "Inspect Element" and I can actually see the data. It is not visible in the source, but it is visible in inspect element for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The source its what cames from the server and the inspect its your browser representation of the information

try to get the innerHTML directly from the webelement and not js script

```
table = driver.find_element_by_id("top-player-stats-summary-grid");
```